# arrangement of text file using PHP

Tags: php, html, text-files, fwrite

I am working on a tool to export some data from database to the text files. The code is given below:

```
    $query3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE domain_id=".$domainID." AND type='NS' ORDER BY id ASC, name ASC");
    while($result3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3))
    {
        $type=$result3['type'];
        $content=$result3['content'];
        $result = $result3['name'];
        $length = strlen(".".$domainNAME);
        $string = substr($result, 0, $length*(-1));
        fwrite($fh,$string."                    IN NS ".$content."\n");

    }
```

So one of the output text file is like:

```
                             IN NS ns1.example.net.

 team.example.net.                  IN NS ns1.example.net.

 team.example.net.                  IN NS ns2.example.net.

 teamex01.example.net.                  IN NS ns1.example.net.

 teamex01.example.net.                  IN NS ns2.example.net.

 dev.example.net.                   IN NS ns1.example.net.

 dev.example.net.                   IN NS ns2.example.net.
```

I want to output the file like :

```
                                    IN NS ns1.example.net.

 team.example.net.                  IN NS ns1.example.net.

 team.example.net.                  IN NS ns2.example.net.

 teamex01.example.net.              IN NS ns1.example.net.

 teamex01.example.net.              IN NS ns2.example.net.

 dev.example.net.                   IN NS ns1.example.net.

 dev.example.net.                   IN NS ns2.example.net.
```

I want to arrange it by column. IN NS record should be arrange in one column. Is there any way to arrange the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you'll need to pre-iterate through the entire list to get the longest-string-length of the text in the first column with [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen) and then use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/str_pad) when outputting it to make it "pretty".

Try something like this (rough concept):

```
$results = array();
$longestLength = 0;
// loop through the mysql results, store them in a `results`-array and save the longest-name
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $results[] = $result;
    if (($strlen = strlen($result['name'])) > $longestLength) $longestLength = $strlen;
}

// loop through all of the results and output with the desired format
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo sprintf("%s\tIN NS %s\n", str_pad($result['name'], $longestLength), $result['content']);
}
```

Side-note (not answer specific):
It is recommended to not use the old, deprecated `mysql` extension in PHP and instead use the favored [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extensions. Both offer additional features such as prepared-statements and are also more secure against SQL Injection attacks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_pad()` on `$string`:

```
$string = str_pad(substr($result, 0, $length*(-1)), 6, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```

This will add up to six spaces to the end of that string ensuring it is a uniform length.

(The `6` is arbitrary based on the sample you provided above. You'll need to see which value works best for you.)